# Difference of Limit Points a subset of the Limit Point of the Difference

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to figure out if the following is true or not in any topological space involving limit points.  Do there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A'-B'\subseteq (A-B)'$?  So far I can't find any counterexamples to show its false, nor a proof that it is valid either and I've spent days trying.  Help please!

Comment: What is your definition of $A'$?

Comment: Yes, the proposition is correct.  The proof uses the fact that x in C' iff x in closure of C\{x}

Comment: By A' I mean the set of limit points of A.

Comment: @Craig.  That is so but what is a limit point?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in A'\setminus B'$. So $x \in A"$ and $x \notin B'$ and the latter means by definition that there is some open neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$, such that $O_x \cap B \subseteq \{x\}$.

Now let $O$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $U = O \cap O_x$ is also an open neighbourhood of $x$, and so we have some point $a \in A \cap U$, with $a \neq x$. As $U \cap B \subseteq O_x \cap B =\{x\}$ we see that $a \notin B$ (if $a \in B$ the previous inclusions would force it to be equal to $x$), and so $a \in A \setminus B$.
So every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains some point $a \in A\setminus B$ with $a \neq x$. This means that $x \in (A\setminus B)'$.

Hence $A'\setminus B' \subseteq (A\setminus B)'$ for all $A,B \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A'-B'$. Then $x\in A'$, so $x\in \overline{A-\{x\}}$ and $x\notin \overline{B-\{x\}}$, as Wiliam Elliot says. Thus $x\in \overline{A-\{x\}}-\overline{B-\{x\}}$. However, $\bar A-\bar B\subseteq \overline{A-B}$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493982/difference-of-closures-and-closure-of-difference) for a proof) so $x\in \overline{(A-\{x\})-(B-\{x\})}=\overline{(A-B)-\{x\}}$. Hence, $x\in (A-B)'$.

Comment: I'd also like to apologize for my initial post, it was 3 in the morning my time, and for some reason my brain convinced me that we were talking about boundary points, even though I mentioned limit points in it :/. Sorry for the confusion