# topology problem and proof

Tags: general-topology

Let $X \not= \emptyset$ and $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space,$H \subseteq X$ and $G \subseteq X$. Show $\overline{H} \setminus \overline{G}\subseteq \overline{H \setminus G } $

Comment: This looks to me like an exercise in juggling definitions; you have closures, set differences and subsets. Have you tried applying the definitions directly?

Comment: By the way, for $X=\emptyset$ it is true.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: H \not = \empteyset$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference of closures and closure of difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493982/difference-of-closures-and-closure-of-difference)

Answer (score 1):

You may write $H$ as
$$H = (H\setminus G)\cup (H\cap G)$$
so that
$$\overline{H} = (\overline{H\setminus G})\cup (\overline{H\cap G})$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\overline{H}\setminus\overline{G}&=((\overline{H\setminus G})\cup (\overline{H\cap G}))\setminus ((\overline{G\setminus H})\cup (\overline{H\cap G}))\nonumber\\
&=(((\overline{H\setminus G})\cup (\overline{H\cap G}))\setminus (\overline{G\setminus H}))\cap (((\overline{H\setminus G})\cup (\overline{H\cap G})) \setminus(\overline{H\cap G}))\nonumber\\
&=(\overline{H}\setminus (\overline{G\setminus H}))\cap(\overline{H\setminus G})\nonumber\\
&\subseteq \overline{H\setminus G} \nonumber
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \overline{H}\setminus\overline{G}$. This means that every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $H$ but there exists an open set $V$ containing $x$ that does not intersect $G$. (By "$A$ intersects $B$", I mean that $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$.)
Fix $V$ as above.

We wish to show that $x \in \overline{H\setminus G}$. Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$.
Then, we have that $U\cap H \neq \emptyset$. (Why?)

**Claim.** $U \cap H \not\subset G$.
*Proof.* Suppose not. Then, we would have $U \cap H \subset G$.
We would also have $V\cap(U\cap H) \subset V\cap G$. However, note that $V \cap G = \emptyset$.
Thus, we get that $V\cap(U\cap H) = \emptyset$ or $(V \cap U) \cap H = \emptyset$.
However, note that $V \cap U$ is an open set containing $x$ (why?) and thus, the above contradicts that $x \in \overline H$. (Why?)
This proves our claim.

Thus, we have shown that $U\cap H\neq\emptyset$ and $U \cap H \not\subset G$. This gives us that
$$U \cap (H \setminus G) \neq \emptyset.$$
(Why?)

As $U$ was an arbitrary open set containing $x$, we are done.

---

Note that I haven't assumed $G \subset H$. Also, make sure that you understand the definitions of closure and complements well. Else, you would have trouble understanding the above.